# How can I share code between two models in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have three or four methods that are the same across three mongoose models. Is there way to define these methods in one file and include them?

```
aSchema.methods.onTimeout = function() {
  // same do stuff like in bSchema
}

bSchema.methods.onTimeout = function() {
  // same do stuff like in aSchema
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the mongoose plugin functionality is for.

In `timeout.plugin.js`:

```
module.exports = exports = function(schema) {
  schema.methods.onTimeout = function() {
    console.log(this._id);
  };
};
```

Then you can use the plugin in your schema this way:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var timeoutPlugin = require('./timeout.plugin');

var MySchema = new Schema({
    // fields here
}, {});

MySchema.plugin(timeoutPlugin);
```

You can do this for any schema you in which want to have `onTimeout` available.

Answer (score 2):

define the common function separately and assign it to them both

```
function onTimeout() {
  // same do stuff like in both
}

aSchema.methods.onTimeout = onTimeout

bSchema.methods.onTimeout = onTimeout
```

It can be in a separate file

**on-timeout.js**

```
module.exports = function onTimeout() {
  // same do stuff like in both
}
```

**a-schema.js**

```
var onTimeout = require('./on-timeout.js');
aSchema.methods.onTimeout = onTimeout
```